# Summing two columns in ArcGIS Desktop, one of them has Null values

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator

I need to sum values of 2 columns in field calculator and populate a new column with the result, one of the values always in Null. I already had found a useful answer [In here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/64815/70335), but it doesn't help with the last couple of columns, that contain a date in DD.MM.YYYY (string) format- geoprocessing report shows successful operation, but the new column stays empty. Is there a small tweak i could use for the code, to make it work?

`def stack(Y, Y_1):
  itemList = [Y, Y_1]
  myList = [Y for Y in itemList if (Y != None)]
  return sum(myList)`

```
Field value= stack( !Y!, !Y_1!)
```

[image: Data table]

Comment: Can you add your code?

Comment: Added the code to the question.

Comment: Have you tried converting the Nulls to 0 and then trying to calculate the fields? Try if Y is None, return 0. Then go ahead and try your calculation again

Comment: Can you also show the table with the fields and what type of data it has?

Comment: I haven't tried converting Nulls to 0, but the code worked well with Nulls, when calculating double format data, these are string.

Comment: Are you trying to add two strings together? Need to know what youre trying to accomplish? If they are dates, in a date format, this can be done with some python

Comment: Basically i want to add the two columns together, because one of them always has Null, the other a value (approximately half of the valuable data stored in each column). They are stored in string and should stay string after calculation, too.

Comment: so some data is in one field, and some in another. What happens if there is data in both columns for a row?

Comment: As i said before, one of the columns always has data, the other always is Null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments, it sounds like `sum` is not quite the right name for the field.  You want to **coalesce** two fields.

```
Field value = !Y! or !Y_1!
```

[This post on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4978738/2258) can give you more background on coalesce.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below. It looks into the first column (date) and if there nothing in it, will return that into the sum field. And vice versa for the date_1 field.

```
def stack (date, date_1, date_sum):
    if date is None:
        return date_1
    else:
        return date

date_sum = stack (!date!, !date_1!, !date_sum!)
```

Comment: This code produced error 000989 on line2.

Comment: Have you tried the edited version? Ok

Comment: Sorry, the code still gives an error, but Richard's suggestion with coalesce did the trick!