# Summing up values in rows with exceptions in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, expression, summarizing

I have given my objects multiple value that represent a "need for action". I want to sum up those individual numbers to an overall "pressure for action".

I have multiple objects with values in ~10 fields.
Sometimes, fields do not have a value (`NULL`). Sometimes I have a `99` as an error value.

If I just sum up my fields by `"field1" + "field2" + "field3" + ...`, I end up with `NULL` as result, if there was a `NULL` in any value. So I need to exclude `NULL` values from my expression. Also, I want to exclude my `99` values.

Sample data:

| id | field1 | field2 | field3 | field4 | expected result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | *NULL* | 2 | 17 | **24** |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 9 | **13** |
| 3 | 0 | 2 | *99* | 12 | **14** |
| 4 | *NULL* | 1 | *99* | 19 | **20** |

I am looking for either an expression I can use or if only possible with Python, a code that I can just copy/paste and edit my column names (I do not know Python, so I would need a proper explanation of the code).
I imagine a code that first checks the value of a field. If the value is `NULL` or 99, it skips to the next field. All other values get added up.

I found this question : [Calculating field in which null values may be present?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/62609/calculating-field-in-which-null-values-may-be-present), which describes a somewhat same problem, but is focused on ArcGIS. I also have no clue what the given code there says and how to adapt it to my problem.

I can not change the numbers in my value fields as they are important on their own.

I am using QGIS 3.24 on Windows 10.

Comment: Are you asking how the [`sum`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html?highlight=sum#sum) expression works with a filter?

Comment: I don't know - do I?

Comment: why don't you just reassign the null and 99 values as zero(0) which has no effect on sum operation?

Comment: @RS_girl as I stated I need those values to stay as there is a different meaning wether the object has 0, 99 or NULL as value and I will continue to work with the other columns on their own as well

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Case 1. Sum of all fields, except `NULL` and 99 values

```
array_sum(array_filter(map_avals(attributes($currentfeature)), @element not in (99)))
```

It sums up all fields of a feature except for values `99` or `NULL`. You can add more values to exclude to the list `not in (99)` if you wish. There is no need to exclude `NULL`, as `array_filter()` will automatically ignore these.

*Note: This will also add the `"id"` field to the sum. To exclude it, see solution 2 or 3*

---

### Case 2. Sum of specific fields, except `NULL` and 99 values

In case you do not want to sum all fields, but only some specific, you can use a slightly different expression:

```
array_sum(array_filter(array("a","b","c"), @element not in (99)))
```

Specify the field names within the array. Here `array("a","b","c")`.

---

### Case 3. Sum of all fields, except one fixed specified field (e.g. `"id"`) and except `NULL` and 99 values

In case you want to sum up all fields, except for one and not list them by hand, you can do it like this:

```
array_sum(array_filter(map_avals(map_delete(attributes($currentfeature), 'id')), @element not in (99)))
```

This deletes the `"id"` field from the sum, but takes all other fields into account.

---

### Explanation on the expression

`attributes($currentfeature)` will return a dictionary (a map) of all fieldnames and values of the current feature. To turn this into an array of only fieldvalues we can use `map_avals()`. Before doing that, we can filter out single fields by using `map_delete()` if wanted.

Similar to `attributes()` does `array("field1", "field2")`. The difference here is that it will not return a dictionary of field name and value, but only the values as array, therefore here `map_avals()` is not needed.

In both cases we now have an array of the desired field values. To filter out `NULL` and other specific values we can use `array_filter()`. This expression iterates over the array and during the iteration we can access the current value by using `@element`. By doing a comparison (`not in (x)` or `<> x`) we can filter the values to keep. `array_sum()` finally sums up all values within the remaining array.

To fully understand complex expressions, I can suggest to split it into parts and just try out what the result of each part is. Additionally you can read up in the [QGIS Docs | List of functions](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html).

Comment: I was just up to put the answer @_@ : `array_sum(array_filter(array("field1", "field2", "field3"),@element != 99))`

Comment: Be careful `map_avals(attributes($currentfeature))` will also consider the `"id"` field

Comment: Thanks! Option B is exactly what i was looking for as there are many more other fields in my real table that should not be considered. Definitely either the expression explanations or just my translation could be improved for beginners, I think. I keep comin here for the most simple questions, just because I don't understand the expressions and what they do.

Comment: Thanks, that explanation really helped! afaik the list in the docs only shows the same texts you get, when clicking on the expressions in field calc. As a GIS advanced user or if you're keen on programming in general, that may suffice, but as a GIS beginner with no knowledge of programming I tend to find my limit in understanding what I have to input as filter, exception, value, etc.